# User defined component in a senchatouch list item

Tags: javascript, extjs

Is there a way to use a user defined sencha touch component (Ext.extend ) as the panel for each item in s a sencha touch list control.

- I know I can do this:

  { xtype: 'list', itemTpl" '{data property 1}'}

To produce this

Ext.List

```
-------------------------------------------
| HTML from itemTpl for listStore Item 1  |
|-----------------------------------------|
| HTML from itemTpl for listStore Item 1  |
|-----------------------------------------|
| HTML from itemTpl for listStore Item 1  |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

What I'd like to do is this:

```
MyComponent = Ext.extend( Ext.Panel ) { Items: [ Ext.Component1, Ext.Component2 ] }
Ext.reg( 'mycomponent', MyComponent );

{ xtype: 'list', itemTpl: { Ext.MyComponent } }
```

to produce something like this

```
-----------------------------------
| { xtype: 'mycomponent' }        |
|---------------------------------|
|  { xtype: 'mycomponent' }       |
|---------------------------------|
| { xtype: 'mycomponent' }        |
|---------------------------------|
```

So that every List item in the lists is rendered as my user defined component.

Is this possible?  Is ther an example somewher?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.define('Ext.TextField',{
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Text',
    xtype: 'TextField',
    labelAlign: 'right',
    listeners: {
        beforerender : function(){
            // var tmp = new Ext.util.TextMetrics("asdfasdf");
            this.labelWidth = gTextUtil.getWidth( this.getFieldLabel() ) + 10 + gLeftMargin;
            this.width = this.labelWidth + 100;
        }
    }
});
```

How to use :

```
{ xtype:'MTATextField', fieldLabel:'or Other' }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any component to any div in Dom using renderTo property. Just add any qualified

```
<div class='someclass-{id} .wrapper'/>
```

into your list item template, then
query .wrapper.someclass-{id} and use renderTo creating components during list refresh event. Please don't forget to remove old unused components later. In this case it's on your responsibility. Components added in such way are managed by Component Manager, but have no parent.